# Returning a String of values from a tree

Tags: java, string, data-structures, tree, preorder

Ok so i want to traverse a tree with inorder, preorder and postorder. I got the right algorithms for traversing the tree but i need to return the String in the Form of `"Node1 Node2 Node3"` but i have `"Node1Node2Node3"`. Here is my code for the preorder:

```
public String PreOrder() {
        /* TODO: Implement */
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        preorderRecursive(string, root);
        return string.toString();
    }
    public StringBuilder preorderRecursive(StringBuilder string, Node current){
        if (current != null) {
        string.append(current.key);
        preorderRecursive(string, current.left);
        preorderRecursive(string, current.right);
        }
        return string;
    }
```

and i get the error `org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<3[ 1 2 8 4 5 7 9 ]10> but was:<3[1284579]10>`

Comment: What's the difference between the expected and actual output? The spaces between the numbers? You can easily add those.

Comment: yes the spaces between the numbers, but when i put string.append(current.key + " ") i get the error:  org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<3 1 2 8 4 5 7 9 10[]> but was:<3 1 2 8 4 5 7 9 10[ ]> (notice the space between the brackets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a space to the stringBuilder,

```java
if (current != null) {
   string.append(current.key).append(" ");
   ...
```

Comment: i had this idea already, but then i get the error: org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<3 1 2 8 4 5 7 9 10[]> but was:<3 1 2 8 4 5 7 9 10[ ]> (notice the space between the brackets)

Comment: if you want to remove the final space, do this
`
string.setLength(string.length()-1);
`
in your PreOrder() method, just before returning